# Why php function call dont complain on having more params

Tags: java, php, .net, function

Why PHP does not complain even when function call have more parameters than function definition ?

But it does complain on less params .

Is it similar on other languages like java or .net

```
function writeMsg($n,$a=false) {

    echo "Hello ".$n;
}

  $name='abc';
  $age = 10;

writeMsg($name,$age,$address,$trash);
```

Comment: In Java the parameters in a method invocation must match the parameters in the method's definition.

Comment: it doesn't complain, because it's not an error, php allows it. those 'extra' arguments are still accessible: http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: `assert( func_num_args() == 2 );` if you care enough.